# Call SWS Via Sabre Red Workspace From Native API Bridge Application

Tags: sabre

I have a requirement to retrieve PNR's from SRW as objects using the native API bridge. I am able to pull the PNR text with an XML wrapper, but that soesn't allow object access. I have tried calling Sabre Web Services but have not been able to find any information on calling SWS via the bridge. Is it possible to call SWS via the native API bridge from a 3rd party application? Can anyone point me to documentation/example on how to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Jeff, you should use the method GetSessionSecurityTokenRQ in the [sample code](https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/NativeAPI-DotNet-Demo/blob/master/NativeAppWin/Form1.cs) and then use a proxy to any of the webservices methods available at [Dev Studio](https://developer.sabre.com).

Hope this helps. P.